# How to use opengl extensions under linux? (GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 not supported)

Tags: linux, opengl, opengl-3, transform-feedback

I have difficulty understanding the OpenGL extension mechanism. I am developing under Ubunut with OpenGL 3.3/Mesa 10.3.2.

If I run glxinfo, it reveals the desired extension: GL_ARB_transform_feedback3
with glxinfo -l it shows the expected limitation of 4 buffers:
GL_MAX_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFERS = 4

Nevertheless, if I have an OpenGL context 3.3 and run a normal GS with

```
#version 330 core
#extension GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 : require
```

All I get is:
0:4(12): error: extension `GL_ARB_transform_feedback3' unsupported in geometry shader

I have read numerous of webpages and books, I can't figure out, where I am mistaken.

The used hardware is pretty new, a laptop with an intel (i915) graphics adapter and a desktop with a NVIDIA (GTX 7xx) graphics adapter.

Is my understanding of glxinfo wrong?
How can I get this extension to run?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check implementation status from `mesa` site. Geometry shader func is  under developpment for most drivers. Mine (ati rv620) have failed geom shader simple examples...